# Do not want to complete the Future unless the verifyPhoneNumber method is complete

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, firebase-authentication

I want to verify a phone number of a user and then only allow that user to signup. But for this when I call `verifyPhoneNumber` even if I apply `await` it does not wait till the verification is completed. it executes the next line. So what I want to do is unless the either of verificationCompleted, verificationFailed, codeAutoRetrievalTimeout completes I want to wait and then only executes the code which creates the document for the user in database.
Any help will be appreciated!!!

```
static Future signUp(BuildContext context, String name, String phoneNumber,
      String email, String gender) async {
    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (credential) async {
          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        },
        verificationFailed: _verificationFailed,
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async{
          await _codeSent(verificationId, resendToken, context);
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String timeout) {});

    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      await DB.users.doc(auth.currentUser.uid).set({
        name: name,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        email: email,
      });
    }
    return;
  }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FirebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html) *starts* verification.  I expect that its returned `Future` completes when the verification request has been issued, not when recipient has completed verification.

If you really want a `Future` that can be `await`ed, you can use a [`Completer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Completer-class.html).  One way to use it to transform your set of completion callbacks:

```dart
    var verificationCompleter = Completer<PhoneAuthCredential>();
    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (credential) {
          verificationCompleter.complete(credential);
        },
        verificationFailed: (error) {
          verificationComplete.completeError(error);
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async{
          await _codeSent(verificationId, resendToken, context);
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String id) {
          verificationComplete.completeError(
            TimeoutException('Verification request timed out'),
          );
        },
    );

    PhoneAuthCredential credential;
    try {
      credential = await verificationComplete.future;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      _verificationFailed(error);
      return;
    } on TimeoutException {
      // Handle a timeout error however you like.
      // ...
      return;
    }

    await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you `.then` clause. so in your code you can attach it like below. the `value` parameter holds any information passed from the code awaited for the `then` clause.

```
static Future signUp(BuildContext context, String name, String phoneNumber,
  String email, String gender) async {
await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    verificationCompleted: (credential) async {
      await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    },
    verificationFailed: _verificationFailed,
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async{
      await _codeSent(verificationId, resendToken, context);
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String timeout) {}).then((value){
        //Code you want to execute after the above is completed.
        if (auth.currentUser != null) {
           await DB.users.doc(auth.currentUser.uid).set({
              name: name,
              phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
              email: email,
           });
        }
        return;
      });
}
```